# Return a unique dataframe name from function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I would like to return several dataframes from def function using unique names based on variables. My code as follows:

```
def plots_without_outliers(parameter):
    """
    The function removes outliers from dataframe variables and plots boxplot and historams
    """
    Q1 = df[parameter].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df[parameter].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    df_without_outliers = df[(df[parameter] > (Q1-1.5*IQR)) & (df[parameter] < (Q3+1.5*IQR))]

    g = sns.FacetGrid(df_without_outliers, col='tariff', height=5)
    g.map(sns.boxplot, parameter, order=['ultra', 'smart'], color='#fec44f', showmeans=True)
          
    g = sns.FacetGrid(df_without_outliers, col='tariff', height=5)
    g.map(plt.hist, parameter, bins = 12, color='#41ab5d')  
        
    return df_without_outliers
```

Then I pass a number of variables :

```
plots_without_outliers('total_minutes_spent_per_month')
plots_without_outliers('number_sms_spent_per_month')
```

In addition to graphs I want to have dataframes returned with unique names to use them later on. For example:
df_without_outliers_total_minutes_spent_per_month
and
df_without_outliers_number_sms_spent_per_month

What would be the best way to deal with this issue? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to deal with this is by using a dictionary, which you can make a global variable outside of the function and then update with the returned dataframe and the corresponding name as dictionary key.

```
dict_of_dfs = dict()

def plots_without_outliers(parameter):
    # your function statements
    return df_without_outliers

for col in ['total_minutes_spent_per_month', 'number_sms_spent_per_month']:
    dict_of_dfs['df_without_outliers_' + col] = (
        plots_without_outliers(col)
    )
```

You can then get each dataframe from the dictionary with e.g., `dict_of_dfs['df_without_outliers_total_minutes_spent_per_month']`

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. If I am right, this approach works in one go thanks to dictionary. It is fine for me, but, for example if I want to plot graphs in different places of my code in Jupyter notebook. Passing variables (or columns) individually helped me to place the output where I needed it.

Comment: You can still pass columns individually with a dictionary. Use `dict_of_dfs['df_without_outliers_total_minutes_spent_per_month']['total_minutes_spent_per_month']`.  Or assign dataframe to a new variable: `df = dict_of_dfs['df_without_outliers_total_minutes_spent_per_month']`.